# Cannot capture photo with custom camera

Tags: swift, avfoundation, ios-camera

I am trying to display an image taken from my custom camera (from a snapchat-like menu where you swipe right to open the camera on the left). I updated the code to 3.0 but now it gives me this error:
**'AVCapturePhotoOutput' has no member 'captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection'**, and I can't find a way to fix it.
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

```
    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession?.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd1920x1080

    let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)

    do {
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera!)

        if (captureSession?.canAddInput(input) != nil) {
            captureSession?.addInput(input)

            stillImageOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

            captureSession?.addOutput(stillImageOutput!)
            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession!)
            previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
            cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
            captureSession?.startRunning()
        }

    } catch {
        print("Something is wrong with the camera")
    }

}
func didPressTakePhoto() {
        if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput?.connection(with: AVMediaType.video) {
            videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
            stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {
                (sampleBuffer, error) in

                if sampleBuffer != nil {
                    var imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jsegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                    var dataProfider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(imageData)
                    var cgImageRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dataProvider, nil, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault)

                    var image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)

                    self.tempImageView.image = image
                    self.tempImageView.isHidden = true
                }


            })
        }
    }
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    didPressTakePhoto()
}
```

I noticed that stillImageOutput is deprecated and now AVCapturePhotoOutput is used instead.
What is the proper way to write captureStillImageAsynchronously in 3.0 (with AVCapturePhotoOutput)?

I saw the other answers for this question and none of them works for me.
All I want is to capture a photo on tap(action) which previews the photo (where I can accept it and do other logic once I accept it).

Answer (score 2):

```
let photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
photoSettings.isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled = true
photoSettings.isHighResolutionPhotoEnabled = true
photoSettings.flashMode = .auto
stillImageOutput?.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: self)

extension YourViewController: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    func photoOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, ..., error: Error?) {
        guard error == nil, let photoSampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer else { return }
        guard let imageData = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: photoSampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewPhotoSampleBuffer) else { return }
        let capturedImage = UIImage(data: imageData, scale: 1.0)
        ...
    }
}
```

Typed in by hand, please forgive any typos.